# Bootstrap 4 - IE11 - row with align-center-self losing width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, flexbox, bootstrap-4, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to align my .row - element centered on the y-axix in IE11 but it doesn't seem to work.

My HTML:

```
<section class="home-section">
    <div class="container home-section-inner d-flex">
        <div class="row align-self-center">
            <div class="offset-lg-1 col-lg-8 ">
                <h1 class="approach-hero text-white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor</h1>
                <p class="approach-hero--quote text-muted">Quote Lorem Ipsum</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

MY CSS:

```
html,body {
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.home-section {
    height: calc(100vh - 30px);
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
    margin: 15px;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(31, 64, 120, 0.9), rgba(31, 64, 120, 0.9)),url(https://placeimg.com/1920/1080/arch) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}

.home-section .home-section-inner {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/grmnn/pen/mxbdGe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `w-100` to the `row` is a workaround...

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wmwadO

This is most likely an IE/Edge flexbox bug.